# System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have a working copy of asp.net mvc site locally.  I just uploaded the whole site to my web hosting server.  everything looks fine at first but when i login, i get the following error:

**System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.**

```
[ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'provider'.]
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean firstKey) +4907604
   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules) +98
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String connectionString) +55
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous) +24
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(String connectionString, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions& userConnectionOptions) +200
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(String value) +62
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value) +4
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString) +24
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +54

[ArgumentException: An error occurred while attempting to initialize a System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection object. The value that was provided for the connection string may be wrong, or it may contain an invalid syntax.
Parameter name: connectionString]
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder..ctor(String connectionString) +136
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +134
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String username, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& passwordFormat, String& passwordSalt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +815
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +105
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String username, String password, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) +42
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +78
   SalemGolf.Controllers.AccountMembershipService.ValidateUser(String userName, String password) in D:\Adam\Code\CSharp\Asp.net\SalemGolf\SalemGolf\Controllers\AccountController.cs:335
   SalemGolf.Controllers.AccountController.ValidateLogOn(String userName, String password) in D:\Adam\Code\CSharp\Asp.net\SalemGolf\SalemGolf\Controllers\AccountController.cs:207
   SalemGolf.Controllers.AccountController.LogOn(String userName, String password, Boolean rememberMe, String returnUrl) in D:\Adam\Code\CSharp\Asp.net\SalemGolf\SalemGolf\Controllers\AccountController.cs:59
   lambda_method(ExecutionScope , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +178
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +24
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__7() +53
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +258
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassc.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__9() +20
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +193
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +382
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +123
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext) +144
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext) +7
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +181
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The value that was provided for the
>   connection string may be wrong, or it
>   may contain an invalid syntax.

My suggestion is to fix the configuration string.

Answer (score 9):

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) contains all allowed keyword values within the ConnectionString for SqlConnection object. "Provider" is not in the list.

You have two options:

- remove "provider" keyword;
- use an [OleDbConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) instead of SqlConnection.

Answer (score 4):

Also When your connection string parameter "User ID" use the space, if it is written as "UserID" then also it gives error

Answer (score 3):

Remove `"Provider=MSDORA"` from your connection string. And then this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Watch for keywords in the connectionstring which NEED spaces. Like `User ID` is correct but `UserID` will fail.